# Keyboard shortcuts in Acrobat's Reading Order panel?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

What are the keyboard shortcuts for tagging content via Adobe Acrobat's Reading Order panel? In the panel, I see underlined letters in each tag button. The "Cell" button has an underlined "e", but pressing the "e" key after selecting content in my PDF does not do anything, however.

I'm not seeing anything in the Acrobat docs ([keyboard shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html) nor [Reading Order tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/touch-reading-order-tool-pdfs.html)).

Running Adobe Acrobat Pro on Windows 10.